# unable to add cookie in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, session-cookies

Below is the cookie which i generated in my postman,

CAKEPHP=4c0nshbqn0vnsn92665dt23lsrpns; Path=/; Domain=.devappium.bizom.in; Secure; HttpOnly; Expires=Sun, 02 May 2021 13:58:52 GMT;

I have added the same in http cookie manager but still it is not working.Let me know whether is there anything wrong in my configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookie name is `CAKEPHP` and should check also Secure

Comment: I tried the same but no luck :( ..updated the image in my first comment pls cehck

Comment: @SadhaNanda Probably the domain has typo or not equal to domain in Http Request

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should not be manually adding cookies, JMeter's HTTP Cookie Manager automatically extracts the cookies from the server's response [Set-Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) and stores them internally in the HTTP Cookie manager (given the cookies are [valid](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265))

Then when you make a next request the HTTP Cookie Manager checks domain and path and if there is a match - it adds the cookie to the request by generating appropriate [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header

The same applies to manually added cookies, if you cannot see the cookie being added to the request you can:

- check the domain and path
- you can turn off JMeter's cookie verification logic by choosing a less restrictive implementation, i.e. `netscape`

  [image]
- there is also a property which completely turns off cookies verification, if you add the next line to *user.properties* file:

  ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
  ```

  this way JMeter will store each and every incoming cookie
- and last but not the least you can [increase JMeter's logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the HTTP Cookie Manager by adding the following line to *log4j2.xml* file:

  ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
  ```
- finally you can always add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send the `Cookie` header with the value you're using in Postman